# Rails order by 2 columns not working as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have `match` table which have 2 field `match_date` and `match_time`. `match_date` is of `date` data type and `match_time` is of `time` data type. I want to get all records order by `match_date` and `match_time` in ascending order. My query looks like this:

```
tournament = Tournament.find_by(name: 'Test')
matches = tournament.matches.order(:match_date, :match_time)
```

when I do `matches.first.match_time` it's showing `match_time` is `11:00 am`. But I also have match with `match_time` of `10:40 am`. So I was hoping `matches.first.match_time` to return `10:40 am` but I am getting result of `11:00 am`. What am I doing wrong ? My query is definitely not giving me desired output.

**UPDATE:** I also tried to use `sort_by` but I am getting same output. My sort_by query looks like this

```
matches = tournament.matches.sort_by{ |a| [a.match_date, a.match_time] }
```

I also don't have any `default_scope` in match model.

Comment: First is ordered by `match_date` ASC, then `match_time` ASC. What is match_date for those with 10:40 and 11 ? What db type have those two fields?

Comment: @razvans match_date is coming correct. I got match_date as 1st Oct. `match_date` datatype is `date` and `match_time` datatype is `time`

Comment: I guess you should provide a bit more information here, at least some example of records which you have and query results. I think there is also possible case if you do it on the Model level then when you do `matches.first.match_time` rails actually use not the results from your variable but original relation, so associated objects will not be ordered. Try just give another name for your variable :)

Comment: @MykhailoMatrosov changing variable name is not going to fix this problem.

Comment: You should provide some sample data, because the code should work. Do you have anything on the `has_many :matches` in your `Tournament` class?